# Android: can't retrieve the image url from mysql database and display it in imageView

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, imageview

i am new to android and facing problem in retrieving image url from mysql database which is present in server
i can retrieve the String using Hashmap but image url cannot be retrieved from the database

i have use adapter class to link listview and imageview,textview etc

can anyone check the below code such that i can retrieve the image path and link it to imageView 
and display the image from the database inserted path.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Permission StrictMode
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    // listView1
    final ListView lstView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 

    String url = "http://192.168.1.2/Android/App/sample.php";

    try {
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("title", c.getString("title"));
            map.put("artist", c.getString("artist"));
            map.put("duration", c.getString("duration"));
            map.put("image", c.getString("image")); i cant retrieve the image string here is the only problem


            MyArrList.add(map);
        }           

        lstView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,MyArrList));

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context context;
    public ImageView imageView;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) 
    {

        context = c;
        MyArr = list;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return MyArr.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null); 
        }

        // ColImage
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        //imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 50;
        //imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 50;
        //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
         try
         {
             URL url = new URL("image");
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             // When Error
             imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
         }

        // ColPosition
        TextView tv_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tv_title.setText("ID : " + MyArr.get(position).get("title"));

        // ColPicname
        TextView tv_artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        //tv_artist.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
        tv_artist.setText("Desc : " + MyArr.get(position).get("artist"));

        TextView tv_duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        //tv_artist.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
        tv_duration.setText("Desc : " + MyArr.get(position).get("duration"));

        TextView tv_link = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.link);
        //tv_artist.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
        tv_link.setText("Desc : " + MyArr.get(position).get("link"));

        return convertView;

    }

} 

/*** Get JSON Code from URL ***/
public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(client);
    try 
    {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) 
        { 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                str.append(line);
            }
        }   
        else 
        {
            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download file..");
        }
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str.toString();
}


private static final String TAG = "ERROR";
private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        copy(in, out);
        out.flush();

        final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //options.inSampleSize = 1;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
    } finally {
        closeStream(in);
        closeStream(out);
    }

    return bitmap;
}

 private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Could not close stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

 private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
        out.write(b, 0, read);
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

sample.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("testdatabase", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sample");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output[] = $row;}

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

activity_column.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"      
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"   
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
       />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title Of Song-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Artist Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    />

<!-- Rightend Duration -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <!-- Rightend Arrow -->    
 <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/link"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
     android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Database data is as follows 
[image]

i dont know where i have missed the methods 
thanks for you time and your concern
i am not able to retrieve image path as well
to check if the image path is retrieving i have created one dummy textview tv_link above in mainActivity.java  but i am getting value as null

Answer (score 0):

**You´re using a wrong IP direction.**

If you´re using localhost to test the ip should be '10.0.0.2' not 192.168.1.2 that must be is your local ip address from your lan but, in android emulation the address of localhost is not 172.0.0.1 or yor LAN ip 192.168.1.2

**You must use 10.0.0.2**

```
String url = "http://10.0.0.2/Android/App/sample.php";
```

**and**

```
http://10.0.0.2/Android/pictures/sandeep1.jpg
```

on the url of your image in your database

if you´re sure that the url String is fine try with HttpURLConnection

```
try {

                URL url = new URL(imagen);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                foto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {


                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

if there is a error it will be detailed in the catch block

Comment: no that is not going to work on my static ip is working as far as i know pal @UrielUVD i guess i have left out some methods can u please check it out for me

Comment: but i can populate all the other string except the image file inside imageView @UrielUVD thanks for your time

Comment: I just added a method in the post to get the image and check out what´s wrong with the Url, hope it help you

Comment: if the problem is that the String is not retrieved it must be wrong named in the Json or is null

Comment: ya sure hey just check my above code in main activity.java once pls such that i can get one idea i have added your code but it is giving an error so can u modify the above code @UrielUVD

Comment: I can´t see what is wrong.
The name in the table is the same as asked in the Jsonobject
i can´t figure out why it si not retrieving the String, sorry u.u

Comment: ya i check it and i got the link it is popping up correctly but how to link it to imageview do u know @UrielUVD

Comment: i have the link now http://192.168.1.2/Android/App/sandeep1.jpg but i have to link it to imageview and display image there @UrielUVD can u help me in this

Comment: Thank you dude i solved it pal thanks for spending time with me @UrielUVD

Comment: No instead of link in the above code i have to pass image it will work fine thanks for your help @UrielUVD